# How can I create a Mail Merge that sends pdfs

Tags: microsoft-word, email, pdf, mail-merge

I'm looking to do a mail merge type application that can attach a specific pdf for each data field, i.e. so that each person gets their own pdf document, which are already created. I have used a naming convention which will allow me to easily attribute each pdf to a person/email in either Microsoft Excel or Access if necessary.

Any help or thoughts are welcome!

*Edit:

I have been looking at https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MailMerge/MergeWithAttachments.htm
and although it looks promising, I can't figure out

1) how to make the mail merge spit out a table in a word doc and

2) how to run the VBA properly (everytime I try it says "Compile error: User-defined type not defined"

Comment: You want to make a document, but the documents are already created?  Are you trying to do a bulk email?

Comment: I want to make a bulk email yes, with each email having an different file attached. I guess my wording could have been better

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar exercise.

I am not actually using a mail merge to generate the letters.  I have placed fields in the letter such as <> and then use VBA to find and replace the field with the appropriate name from my spreadsheet.

My system so far will process a data file, create the individual letter and save as DOCX.  Working on saving it now as a PDF.

I will then work on attaching the file to an email.

Comment: Any ideas as of right now on how to attach the files?

Answer (score 0):

To make a table merge in Word:

- Mailings > Start Mail Merge > Directory
- Mailings > Select Recipient List > choose your excel file
- Insert > Table > Choose one row with proper number of columns
- Mailings > Insert Merge Field - place data field into first cell, then do same for each column.
- Mailings > finish and merge > edit individual documents.
- Save your file, this is your source as referred to in your instructions.